# Is it possible to transform a string of React components to a string of HTML

Tags: reactjs

I saw `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)` can do something similar but `element` input is not a String I guess.

Comment: React elements are not strings. There's no such thing as "a string of React elements ".

Comment: @Puppy thanks for the information. So meaning it's not possible to do something like a CMS where you can use React components inside a wysiwyg editor and then compile them in run-time right?

Comment: What? I think that you have no idea what you are trying to express or discuss.

Comment: @Puppy Sorry if my explanation is not clear. Basically I want Editors to use react components when writing a post for example (via our CMS), is it possible? Given the fact that the front-end is built with React? We can do it with Angular's $compile service. Don't know how react handles it...

Answer (score -1):

are you looking for something like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html